# How may I express concern without asking if the person is 'OK' but wanting them to be 'OK'?

Tags: idioms, greetings

How may I express concern without asking if the person is 'OK' but wanting them to be 'OK'?

It's not obvious how to do so in English. In English you might say something like "get well soon", but that's not quite what I mean

> A friendly or polite phrase used to wish someone well when they are
>   ill.

I'm looking for a standard phrase or idiom.

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language stack exchange. General translation requests without any evidence of research or a specific language question are considered off topic on this site. Can you try to make an attempt and frame the question from the perspective of what you've found?

Comment: hi @Leebo where can i search Japanese idioms?

Comment: @Leebo i googled "express concern" and "japanese" and got nothing at all

Comment: Jisho had a tag for idiomatic expressions, but it probably has too many results to just sift through. https://jisho.org/search/%23words%20%23id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get well soon - [お大事に]{おだいじに}.

Comment: do you have anything to add about this phrase?

Comment: @vqlk I learned it some time in the past. But you can find something here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6032 So it's kind of a duplicate.

Comment: thanks for the link. take care, is the english expression, i s'pose. thanks

Comment: @vqlk, if this answers your question, you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the grey tick mark at the left of the answer. Thanks!

Comment: can you edit in the link @jarmanso7

Comment: You can edit your own questions by clicking on 'edit', I edited this one for you, but as I do not have enough reputation, it is to be confirmed by someone else.