# Word choice to mean "take care of yourself"

Tags: word-choice

> ご無事で - Take care of yourself
>   大事にして - Take care of yourself

What's the difference in the sentences? Is ご無事 more formal? Or is there a better word to mean "take care of yourself"?

Comment: See also [ご自愛](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%94%E8%87%AA%E6%84%9B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say お気を付けて, お大事に, お元気で, etc. For the difference, see: [Difference between 気をつけて, お大事に and お元気で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6032/5010)

ご無事で is more like "I prey for your safety" or "Stay alive". Don't use it unless someone is going to be truly in danger.

大事にする by itself means "to value" or "to treasure". To say "to take care of yourself", you need an object (お体を大事にしてください). お大事に is an idiom that makes sense on its own.